# How to Move commit(contains 2-3 files) from one branch to another branch using cherry-pick or any other method

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two branches, in that one is `master` branch and another is `development` branch.

I have been trying to move commits from `development` to `master` using `cherry-pick` method. This method worked well for me if the commit has edited or updated in any one file. But in my scenario, The two to three files edited and pushed in single commit. I need to move those commit to my `master` branch.

So when I tried `cherry-pick`, I couldn't move it out. I was able to move only single-file edited in single commit and wasn't able to move multi-files edited in single commit. I am looking out here solution for the issue.

Comment: What happened when you tried to cherry-pick the commit that edited multiple files?

Comment: When I tried with 3 files, it got conflicted  in 2 files and one file was not conflicted in moving by cherry-pick.. same thing was happened when I tried with 4 files.. 3 files were conflicted and 1 file was not conflicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick`, you'll just have to resolve your merge conflicts. See [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Thanks Aleksey Tsalolikhin. The link you shared which helped to solve the conflicts in my files and was able to move commits to my ```master``` branch using ```cherry-pick``` method now.

Answer (score 1):

suppose commit-a, commit-b commit-c are your three commits on development branch which you want to move to master
To move first commit, run:

```
git cherry-pick <sha-id-of-commit-a>
```

resolve the conflicts, add to index and run

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

then move the second commit

```
git cherry-pick <sha-id-of-commit-b>
```

resolve the conflicts, add to index and run

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

then move the third commit

```
git cherry-pick <sha-id-of-commit-c>
```

resolve the conflicts, add to index and run

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Comment: Thanks Tayyab Munir for the steps to copy commits using ```cherry-pick``` method.